# Movie with two parallel universes, each of which is a television show in the other's universe

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe

I didn't expect this to be so difficult to find since it was relatively recent, but my Google searches are turning up nothing but listicles.

Details:

- Most likely made sometime between 2005 and 2015
- The two main characters are a female nurse (doctor?) and a male criminal.
- Each of them exists as a fictional TV character in the other's world.
- Eventually they meet. I think they somehow interact through their televisions, but I don't recall the details.

I was originally pretty sure that it was English-language, but I don't trust my memory on that.

Comment: Interesting movie, and director, and predecessor "Ink"!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is [*The Frame*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frame_(film)) (2014).

> Sam, home after her therapist visit, sits eating dinner in front of the TV and watches Alex's recent heist and escape with the intensity of a true fan. Alex's show is called Thieves and Saints.
>
> Late one evening, as the two have their televisions on, they realize that they are each broadcast live from their living rooms on the other's TV set. They say hello, panic, and turn off their TVs. Each handles the impossibility in a different way – Sam tells her therapist she may be losing her mind, and Alex believes the cartel or cops have him under surveillance.